# Marklogic XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) arg0 is not of type xs:anyAtomicType?

Tags: marklogic

I get an error:

> XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) local:getrole(xs:unsignedLong($perm/sec:role-id)) || "=" || xs:string($perm/sec:capability) -- arg0 is not of type xs:anyAtomicType?

I could not figure what's wrong. I am trying to get a list of permissions for each user. The result should be userA and a list of roles, userB and a list of roles.

```
let $uris := cts:uris(
                  (),
                  (),
                  cts:and-query(
                      cts:collection-query("/users")
                  )
        )
return

    (:loop for each user & assign permission to variable:)
for $user in $uris
let $perm := xdmp:document-get-permissions(($user))

return
<info>

 <user>{$user}</user>
  <roles>{(local:getrole(xs:unsignedLong($perm/sec:role-id)) || "=" || 
  xs:string($perm/sec:capability))}</roles>
</info>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `local:getrole(xs:unsignedLong($perm/sec:role-id)` is returning multiple values, and this is the error you get when trying to concat sequences using the `||` operator.

Since a user can (and likely will) have multiple permissions, you need to loop through those as well.

```
for $user in $uris
for $perm in xdmp:document-get-permissions(($user))
...
```